# Can we use simultaneous row and column operations in solving same determinant?

Tags: matrices, determinant

Please help.. Can both(row and column) operations be used simultaneously in finding the value of same determinant means in solving same question at a single time?

Comment: Yes, but I can't remember how to prove it properly. Maybe you can wait for more qualified people to answer.

Comment: ok thanks for trying

Comment: What does "simultaneous" mean exactly? Row and column operations both modify the determinant in the usual ways.

Comment: By simultaneously i meant that can we use both of them one after other in same question in a single try.It means i proceeded one step in solving by row operations and second step by column operations.Is it correct?

Answer (score 4):

A row operation corresponds to multiplying a matrix $A$ on the left by one of several elementary matrices whose determinants are easy to compute to get a matrix $B = EA$. For instance, swapping the rows of a 2x2 matrix is done with

$$
\pmatrix{0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 } \pmatrix{a & b \\ c & d}
$$
The determinant of the resulting row-swapped matrix is the product of the two determinants. Hence $det B = det E det A$. Since $det E = -1$ in this case, you can compute the det of the new matrix and multiply it be $-1$ to get the det of the original one. (This is typically not very useful, but it's an example).

In the same way, a column op is done with $A \mapsto AE$, and you can use the same rule -- prduct of determinants -- to relate the determinant of $B = AE$ to the determinant of $A$.

In short: you can do a sequence of row and column ops, each of which adds a factor to the determinant, until you reach the identity. You don't have to do just a sequence of row ops or just a sequence of column ops.

Personal advice: Just use one or the other. It'll take a little longer, but you're much less likely to make a mistake in my experience with many students over the years.

Answer (score 3):

Remember that a set of row operations on a matrix $A$ can be represented by a matrix $P$

$$A^{\prime}=PA$$

Here $A^{\prime}$ is the matrix $A$ after the operations. In the same way, column operations are represented by a matrix $Q$ such that

$$A^{\prime}=AQ$$

After both row a column operations you have

$$A^{\prime}=PAQ$$

so

$$\det A^{\prime}=\det P\det Q\det A$$

Here $\det P$ and $\det Q$ are factors that depends on your exact operations: row addition (factor $1$), row transposition (factor $-1$) and row multiplication by $c$ (factor $c^{n}$, where $n\times n$ is the size of the matrices).

Comment: I wanted to ask that if in a problem i proceeded one step by row operation,then can i proceed with second step by column operations in same problem at a time?

Comment: @AdarshDubey That's a perfectly valid thing to do. This is the consequence of the associativity of matrix multiplication. You have a sequence of row operations and a sequence of column operations, *i.e.* $$A^{\prime}=P_{n}\dots P_{1}AQ_{1}\dots Q_{n}$$ You can do all the row operations first, or all the column operations first or one row operation followed by one column operation. It doesn't matter.

Comment: thank you.now i am satisfied..